# Javascript pop up box with a for each php statement

Tags: javascript, php, database

I don't know if this is possible but seems like it should be...

I have a javascript pop up box running on a php for each statement.  The application is a seating chart kind of thing.  There are 50 banquet tables in the database table each with 10 seats and a table id.

I query the database and ask for all fields where the table active field is set to yes.  Then for each table I want to show a pop up form so the user can enter a name for each seat.  The problem is this.  When I open the first instance of the form it shows table id as 1.  When I open the second instance of the form I want it to show table id 2 - but it shows table id 1.  How do i get each instance of the form to show the 'next' table?

Here is the code I am using:

```
     global $wpdb;
$seatings = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM bb_cl_seating WHERE table_active='yes' ");

    if (count($seatings)===0){
    echo "<h2>There are no tables - Would you like to add one?</a>"; 
    } else  {
    foreach($seatings as $seating){
?>

    <!-- link that opens popup -->

<a class="popup-with-form" href="#table-form" onclick="jQuery('#table-form-<?php echo $seating->table_id; ?>').show(); return false;">Open form</a><br />
<!-- form itself -->
<form method="post" id="table-form-<?php echo $seating->table_id; ?>" class="white-popup-block mfp-hide">
    <h1>Celebrity Luncheon Seating</h1>
    <fieldset style="border:0;">

        <ol>
            <li>
            Table Number: <?php echo $seating->table_id; ?>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="seat_one">Seat One</label>
                <input name="seat_one" type="text" id="seat_one" value="<?php echo $seating->seat_one; ?>" size="50" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="seat_two">Seat Two</label>
                <input name="seat_two" type="text" id="seat_two" value="<?php echo $seating->seat_two; ?>" size="50" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="seat_three">Seat Three</label>
                <input name="seat_three" type="text" id="seat_three" value="<?php echo $seating->seat_three; ?>" size="50" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="seat_four">Seat Four</label>
                <input name="seat_four" type="text" id="seat_four" value="<?php echo $seating->seat_four; ?>" size="50" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="seat_five">Seat Five</label>
                <input name="seat_five" type="text" id="seat_five" value="<?php echo $seating->seat_five; ?>" size="50" />
            </li>
            <li>
            <input name='table_id' type='hidden' id='table_id' value='<?php echo $seating->table_id; ?>' /><input name='table_active' type='hidden' id='table_active' value='<?php echo $seating->table_active; ?>' /><input name="update" type="submit" id="Submit" value="update" />
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<?php   } // closes for each ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    $('.popup-with-form').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        preloader: false,
        focus: '#seat_one',

        // When elemened is focused, some mobile browsers in some cases zoom in
        // It looks not nice, so we disable it:
        callbacks: {
            beforeOpen: function() {
                if($(window).width() < 700) {
                    this.st.focus = false;
                } else {
                    this.st.focus = '#name';
                }
            }
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You done big mistack that is you put jQuery function $('.popup-with-form') in loop that will generate lots of function for you and when you try to click that will invoke all to gather else that will not work for you.

So dont put jquery function in loop for when you using . [Dot] operator.

Try this below code

```
  global $wpdb;
$seatings = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM bb_cl_seating WHERE table_active='yes' ");

if (count($seatings)===0){
echo "<h2>There are no tables - Would you like to add one?</a>"; 
} else  {
foreach($seatings as $seating){  ?>

 <!-- link that opens popup -->
<a class="popup-with-form" href="#table-form">Open form</a><br />

<?php  } } ?>


<!-- form itself -->
<form id="table-form" class="white-popup-block mfp-hide">
<h1>Celebrity Luncheon Seating</h1>
<fieldset style="border:0;">

    <ol>
        <li>
        Table Number: <?php echo $seating->table_id; ?>
        </li>

    </ol>
</fieldset>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
// pop up form script
$('.popup-with-form').magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline',
    preloader: false,
    focus: '#name',

    // When elemened is focused, some mobile browsers in some cases zoom in
    // It looks not nice, so we disable it:
    callbacks: {
        beforeOpen: function() {
            if($(window).width() < 700) {
                this.st.focus = false;
            } else {
                this.st.focus = '#name';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

});

```
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of posting the whole code, try to explain what's wrong with the code in the question and how are you correcting it, and only post the relevant changes

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Jigar. New to this and trying to figure- very helpful. However didn't address 'showing the correct record in the pop up links'. My link always shows record 1. I placed the table id in the form id and in an onclick call in the a href.  Still no luck - still looking.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - in the javascript call I needed to get it to know there was more than one...  And also needed to call the bit of javascript for each instance unlike the tip given previously

```
<!-- link that opens popup -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    $('.popup-with-form-<?php echo $seating->table_id; ?>').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        preloader: false,
        focus: '#seat_one',




        // When elemened is focused, some mobile browsers in some cases zoom in
        // It looks not nice, so we disable it:
        callbacks: {
            beforeOpen: function() {
                if($(window).width() < 700) {
                    this.st.focus = false;
                } else {
                    this.st.focus = '#name';
                }
            }
        }
    });
});

</script>   


<a href="#popup-with-form-<?php echo $seating->table_id; ?>" class="popup-with-form-<?php echo $seating->table_id; ?>">Open popup</a><br />


<!-- form itself -->
<div id="popup-with-form-<?php echo $seating->table_id; ?>" class="mfp-hide white-popup">

<form method="post" >
    <h1>Celebrity Luncheon Seating</h1>
    <fieldset style="border:0;">

        <ul>
            <li>
            Table Sponsor: <?php echo $seating->sponsor; ?>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="seat_one">Seat 1</label>
                <input name="seat_one" type="text" id="seat_one" value="<?php echo $seating->seat_one; ?>" size="50" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="seat_two">Seat 2</label>
                <input name="seat_two" type="text" id="seat_two" value="<?php echo $seating->seat_two; ?>" size="50" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="seat_three">Seat 3</label>
                <input name="seat_three" type="text" id="seat_three" value="<?php echo $seating->seat_three; ?>" size="50" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="seat_four">Seat 4</label>
                <input name="seat_four" type="text" id="seat_four" value="<?php echo $seating->seat_four; ?>" size="50" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="seat_five">Seat 5</label>
                <input name="seat_five" type="text" id="seat_five" value="<?php echo $seating->seat_five; ?>" size="50" />
            </li>

        </ul>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset style="border:0;">

        <ul>
            <li>
            Table Celebrity: <?php echo $seating->celebrity; ?>
            <li>
                <label for="seat_six">Seat 6</label>
                <input name="seat_six" type="text" id="seat_six" value="<?php echo $seating->seat_six; ?>" size="50" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="seat_seven">Seat 7</label>
                <input name="seat_seven" type="text" id="seat_seven" value="<?php echo $seating->seat_seven; ?>" size="50" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="seat_eight">Seat 8</label>
                <input name="seat_eight" type="text" id="seat_eight" value="<?php echo $seating->seat_eight; ?>" size="50" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="seat_nine">Seat 9</label>
                <input name="seat_nine" type="text" id="seat_nine" value="<?php echo $seating->seat_nine; ?>" size="50" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="seat_ten">Seat 10</label>
                <input name="seat_ten" type="text" id="seat_ten" value="<?php echo $seating->seat_ten; ?>" size="50" />
            </li>
            <li>
            <input name='table_id' type='hidden' id='table_id' value='<?php echo $seating->table_id; ?>' /><input name='table_active' type='hidden' id='table_active' value='<?php echo $seating->table_active; ?>' /><input name="update" type="submit" id="Submit" value="update" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```